# Heroku Taps load error

Tags: sqlite, heroku, taps

I'm trying to use Heroku Taps but after "gem install taps", I'm still getting the following error when I do "heroku db:pull":

```
heroku db:pull

Taps Load Error: dlopen(/Users/yves/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/yves/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Users/yves/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
```

My setup:

Homebrew

RVM

```
rvm list

rvm rubies

   jruby-1.5.1 [ x86_64-java ]
   ree-1.8.7-2010.02 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p160 [ i386 ]
=> ruby-1.8.7-p302 [ i386 ]
   ruby-head [ i386 ]
```

GEMS

```
gem list

...
heroku (1.17.10)
...
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
taps (0.3.15)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, think I solved it. I installed ruby 1.8.7 again with RVM and that seemed to do the trick. Not sure why though...

```
rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p302
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the Heroku bundle includes a native version sqlite gem that is not compatible with the i386 architecture.

Try to do a `gem update sqlite3 sqlite3-ruby`

Updated: On my Mac OS X Snow Leopard machine, I use rvm to manage ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.3, but I use the system installed ruby 1.8.7 for ruby 1.9 and rails 2.3.8. development. I switch between ruby 1.8 and 1.9 by using 'rvm system' and 'rvm default' (I set up 1.9.2 as my default in rvm.

I noticed when I am running 'rvm system', I get the following:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.8
$ gem list --local | grep taps
taps (0.3.15, 0.3.12, 0.3.10, 0.2.26, 0.2.25)
$ gem list --local | grep sqlite
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3, 1.3.1, 1.2.5, 1.2.4)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Steve, just did "gem update sqlite3 sqlite-ruby" and got this message:


Updating installed gems
Nothing to update